# Discrepancy in disk usage between btrfs fi show and btrfs fi df

Tags: debian, filesystems, btrfs

I'm aware of some btrfs issues with full metadata but mine issue seems different.

I have 2x3TB disks creating *raid0* btrfs filesystem.
I can't understand the difference between disk usage reported by:

```
> btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: 23a6779e-9c8e-4cec-804b-0056451ab782
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 1009.59GiB
        devid    1 size 2.73TiB used 530.02GiB path /dev/sda
        devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 530.01GiB path /dev/sdc

Btrfs v3.17
```

and

```
> btrfs fi df /mnt/btrfs 
Data, RAID0: total=1.03TiB, used=1008.49GiB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MiB, used=96.00KiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00B
Metadata, RAID1: total=2.00GiB, used=1.10GiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00B
GlobalReserve, single: total=384.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

From the first output I presume that my files occupy 530GB from each disk and there is plenty of space still available.

But from the second output I see that instead of ~5TB I have only 1TB available and it's almost full (1008.49GiB used)
Should I be worried? What is the meaning of this discrepancy?

Comment: Also keep in mind that btrfs is using the nonambigous XiB syntax, so: used=1008.49GiB == 1008.49/1024TiB == 0.98TiB. I assume the difference is some type of file system overhead or something. I'm trying to understand how btrfs reports its data for use in a project, but so far am not progressing very well due to how confusing it is compared to other filesystems, particularly to zfs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [btrfs FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#How_much_free_space_do_I_have.3F) explains what each of these commands is showing.

The `btrfs fi show` command shows the disks in the file system, with the size of each and how much has been *allocated* on each disk. Your output does not mean that 530 GiB of data are stored, just that this much space has been set aside for data storage. This is also how the regular `df` command will interpret your filesystem. You are right that there is plenty of space remaining on the devices.

The `btrfs fi df` command provides detail on that *allocated* space. If you add up all of the "total" values, accounting for the RAID1 metadata, you will find that you have about the 1060.03 GiB allocated the `show` command says. The "used" values are how much information is actually stored in the allocated space for each of those formats.

The `btrfs fi df` command cannot tell you how much more data you can store, because that depends on the formats. 1 GiB of data in single/RAID0 will take 1 GiB of your free space on the filesystem, but 1 GiB of metadata in dup/RAID1 will take 2 GiB of free space on the filesystem. It could tell you how much is free on the disks, but it can't tell you how much will be used for storing data and how much will be used for metadata.

Comment: so what you basically sa that the `btrfs fi df` does not show any free disk space, but instead it shows details about "*allocated* space". So to get an idea how much space is available the former `btrfs fi show` is the actual choice?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace the other way around. `show` only shows how much btrfs has allocated. The "used" value from `df` will tell you how much is actually used by files.